# A*Pathfinding generating wrong path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm building a maze game where there's an enemy ready to pursuit the player if the player gets in his range, I'm using A*Pathfinding algorithm to do so, and I build the maze in a procedural way, where each block in the maze has a MapLocation with x and z position, so the start position is the enemy pos and goal is the player position, but sometimes, when the player gets in the range of the enemy,the pathfing ignores some blocks of the maze to get to the player

```
IEnumerator Search(Vector3 start, Vector3 goal)
        {
            pathSuccess = false;
            waypoints = new Vector3[0];
            Heap<Path> open = new Heap<Path>(maze.MaxSize);
            HashSet<Path> closed = new HashSet<Path>();

            Path startNode = new Path(maze.GetMapLocation(start), 0, 0, 0, null);
            Path goalNode = new Path(maze.GetMapLocation(goal), 0, 0, 0, null);

            open.Add(startNode);
            lastPos = startNode;

            while (open.Count > 0)
            {
                if (lastPos.Equals(goalNode))
                {
                    pathSuccess = true;
                    break;
                }
                foreach (MapLocation dir in maze.directions)
                {
                    MapLocation neighbour = dir + lastPos.location;
                    if (maze.map[neighbour.x, neighbour.z] == 1) continue;
                    if (neighbour.x < 1 || neighbour.x >= maze.width || neighbour.z < 1 || neighbour.z >= maze.depth) continue;
                    if (IsClosed(neighbour, closed)) continue;

                    float G = Vector2.Distance(lastPos.location.ToVector(), neighbour.ToVector()) + lastPos.G;
                    float H = Vector2.Distance(neighbour.ToVector(), goalNode.location.ToVector());
                    float F = G + H;

                    if (!UpdateMarker(neighbour, G, H, F, lastPos, open))
                        open.Add(new Path(neighbour, G, H, F, lastPos));
                }
                Path pm = open.RemoveFirst();
                closed.Add(pm);

                lastPos = pm;
            }
            yield return null;
            if (pathSuccess)
            {
                waypoints = RetracePath(startNode);
            }
            PathRequestManager.Instance.FinishedProcessingPath(waypoints, pathSuccess);
        }

        bool UpdateMarker(MapLocation pos, float g, float h, float f, Path prt, Heap<Path> open)
        {
            foreach (Path p in open)
            {
                if (p.location.Equals(pos))
                {
                    p.G = g;
                    p.H = h;
                    p.F = f;
                    p.parent = prt;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool IsClosed(MapLocation marker, HashSet<Path> closed)
        {
            foreach (Path p in closed)
            {
                if (p.location.Equals(marker)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        Vector3[] RetracePath(Path startNode)
        {
            Path begin = lastPos;
            List<Vector3> path = new List<Vector3>();
            while (!startNode.Equals(begin) && begin != null)
            {
                path.Add(begin.Position(maze));
                begin = begin.parent;
            }
            path.Reverse();
            return path.ToArray();
        }

public MapLocation GetMapLocation(Vector3 position)
        {
            MapLocation mapLocation = new MapLocation((int)position.x / scale, (int)position.z / scale);
            return mapLocation;
        }
public List<MapLocation> directions = new List<MapLocation>() {
                                            new MapLocation(1,0),
                                            new MapLocation(0,1),
                                            new MapLocation(-1,0),
                                            new MapLocation(0,-1) };
```

The maze is generated like this:

```
public class Recursive : Maze
    {
        public override void Generate()
        {
            Generate(5, 5);
        }

        void Generate(int x, int z)
        {
            if (CountSquareNeighbours(x, z) >= 2) return;
            map[x, z] = 0;

            directions.Shuffle();

            Generate(x + directions[0].x, z + directions[0].z);
            Generate(x + directions[1].x, z + directions[1].z);
            Generate(x + directions[2].x, z + directions[2].z);
            Generate(x + directions[3].x, z + directions[3].z);
        }

    }



public byte[,] map;
 public virtual void Generate()
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                   if(Random.Range(0,100) < 50)
                     map[x, z] = 0;     //1 = wall  0 = corridor
                }
        }
```

I already tried using Manhattan's Distance and it didn't make any difference:

```
float H = Mathf.Abs(neighbour.x - goalNode.location.x) + Mathf.Abs(neighbour.z - goalNode.location.z);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug the values you getting when you divide by scale in GetMapLocation() it could be skipping cells because of scaling/rounding?

I would have a map[x,y] array, then multiple that by scale to get it right in pixels on the screen, but do the pathfinding on the raw unscaled Map[x,y] array. IE separate logic from rendering.

Comment: I have a map[x,z] which I use to generate the maze, see the edits in the question above

Comment: If your map is in a 2D array, why are you scaling in the GetMapLocation() function?

All node checking should be strait integers in the map array. 

Go into debug and make sure the values you expect for a node are getting returned from GetMapLocation(), not a rounding error to the adjacent cell.

Comment: You can check your logic with the help of Tarodevs most excellent tutorial on A*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0x5fj4PqP4

Comment: you're right my little rat, the GetMapLocation was rounding the results down instead of up, misleading the path.

Comment: Yay, we did it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your A* pathfinding algorithm is related to the generation of your maze. Since you are generating it procedurally, sometimes the pathfinding algorithm can skip some blocks of the maze to reach the player.

You can fix this problem by adjusting the generation of the maze to ensure that it is always possible to reach any point from any other point in the maze.

You can use a maze generation algorithm e.g prim's or kruskal's algorithm.

One more thing i noticed is that the heuristic function you are using to calculate distance from a node to the goal is not idle for a maze try using euclidean or chebyshev distance.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm actually using a recursive method to generate the maze, and I double checked to see if it is possible to reach the player, and it is always possible.